# Collision resolution of strings using double hashing?

Tags: c, hash, hashmap, hashtable, double-hashing

i have an input file having about 10k strings.
I need to count the no. of collisions using open addressing,double hashing.However the code goes into an infinite loop,i.e,its not able to find any empty place to fill at all! (for input greater than 1000).

According to the ques given to me,we are supposed to use this.
**First Hash: Summation of ASCII
Second Hash: Division i.e mod sizeof(Prime)**

Iam think this has something to do with my hash function.

i have created an array of structure for storing strings using the following.

```
struct table{
    char word[50];
};
```

and then created an array as follows:

```
struct table*array=(struct table*)malloc(10000*sizeof(struct table));
```

Below are the 2 hash functions i used:

```
int hash1(char* name) //This function calculates the ascii value
{
    int index=0;int i=0;
    for(;name[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        index+=name[i];
    }
    return index;

}

int hash2(int index) //Calculates offset (mod with a large prime,Why do we do this?)
{
    int offset=index%1021;
    return offset;
}
```

Below is my insert function.

```
insert(char* name)
{
    int offset=0,index=0;
    index=hash1(name);//calculate the index from string
    index=index % 10000;//to keep index between 0-10k range
    while((array[index].word[0]!='\0')) // checking if space in array empty
    {
        collision+=1;    //global counter
        offset=hash2(index); //offset
        index=index+offset;
        index=index%10000;
    }
    strcpy(array[index].word,name);
    return array;

}
```

How can i improve my hash function such that it visit all 10k location on array. ?(or change it  entirely).

According to the ques given to me,we are supposed to use this.
First Hash: Summation of ASCII
Second Hash: Division i.e mod sizeof(Prime)

Comment: If your second hash is just a function of your first, then you're not double hashing at all. The second hash has to be independent. First hash is pretty bad too, but might be good enough for this simple purpose. Try something like FNV. Oh, and make sure your second hash is never 0, and it's better if it's relatively prime to the size of your table.

Comment: How can i change my second function ? since iam not allowed to use other hashing algorithms.(i updated the ques).Yes,i will make sure,the second funcion does not return 0

Comment: If the first hash is part of your assignment, you're kind of stuck with that. This will cause short strings to cluster around the low end of the table. You might make the second hash something like the sum of only the first 8 characters of the string, modulo a very small prime like 97, plus one.

Comment: Also, you said the input has "about" 10000 strings. So why is the table only 10000 entries? Why not give it some headroom, like 12000 or 15000?

Comment: Ok thanks,i will do so.

Comment: It's not realistic to think you won't have any collisions with just 2 hash functions like this: say when adding the last value the table is P percent full: that means even a cryptographic quality general purpose hash function has P percent chance of randomly colliding with an existing value, and that goes for your rehash too, so P^2.  Even if P is just 10%, hence P^2 1%, it you tally that up the last couple hundred elements added you're almost certain to have a double-collision.  You need some backup plan for collision handling, such as a displacement list of other buckets to try.